# Overwriting output in textfile (need to save all outputs)

Tags: java, text-files, overwrite

Hey guys I need my program to be able store multiple outputs, but instead it is just overwriting the same string (total) over and over in the textfile. How can i make it so it will write multiple answers instead of overwriting it? Thank you :)

```
static int boys;
static int girls;
static int total;

public static void program() {



     System.out.println("enter number of girls: ");
     girls = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("enter number of boys: ");
     boys = input.nextInt();
     total = boys+girls;

     System.out.println(total);


}

private static Formatter x;

public void openFile () {
    try {
        x = new Formatter("income.txt");
    }

    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("You have an error");
    }
}

public static void addRecords(){
    x.format("%s%s%s", " 19", " James", " A");
    x.format("%s%s", "\n", total);



}

public void closeFile(){
    x.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `openFile` method to something like this:

```
public void openFile(){
    try {
        Appendable appendable = new FileWriter("income.txt",true);
        x = new Formatter(appendable);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("You have an error");
    }
}
```

The important part is `new FileWriter("income.txt",true);`, this creates a new `FileWriter` that appends data to the `income.txt` file.

You can find more info about that [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean))

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: @Suppaa You're welcome, good luck. Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it has solved your problem.